# Jetpack Compose Navigation:How to pass an array as an argument?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a filter dialog that shows filter options :

[image]

When I click on "Parent Platform" section I'm navigating to the `PlatformsScreen` with two arguments. Argument one is `parent` which is int and the second is platforms which is an array of int :

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, val arguments: List<NamedNavArgument>) {

    object PlatformScreen : Screen(PLATFORM_ROUTE,arguments = 
        listOf(navArgument("parent", builder = {type = NavType.IntType}),
        navArgument("platforms",builder = {type = NavType.IntArrayType})))
}


// click action
@Composable
fun FilterDialog(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: FilterViewModel,
    navigateToPlatformScreen: (Int,Array<Int?>) -> Unit
) {
 val filterState by viewModel.filterState.collectAsState()
 Row(//other stuff
       .clickable {
                    navigateToPlatformScreen(filterState.parentPlatform?.id ?: -1,
                    filterState.platforms?.map { it?.id }?.toTypedArray() ?: arrayOf(-1))
                }
)
  //here is my filter bottom sheet
   bottomSheet(route = FILTER_ROUTE) {
        FilterDialog(viewModel = viewModel,
            navigateToPlatformScreen = { parentId,platforms ->
                navController.navigate("${Screen.PlatformScreen.route}?parent=${parentId}&platforms=${platforms}")
            })
    }

    //platforms screen
    bottomSheet(route = Screen.PlatformScreen.route+"?parent={parent}&platforms={platforms}",arguments = Screen.PlatformScreen.arguments) { backstackEntry ->
        val parent = backstackEntry.arguments?.getInt("parent")
        val platforms = backstackEntry.arguments?.getIntArray("platforms")
        PlatformScreen(parent = parent,platforms = platforms)
    }
```

And as the last part, here is my `FilterViewModel` that holds my `parentId` and `platforms` array :

```
class FilterViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _selectedParentPlatform = MutableStateFlow<ParentPlatform?>(ParentPlatform())

    private val _filterState = MutableStateFlow(FilterState())

    val filterState:StateFlow<FilterState> get() = _filterState

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
           _selectedParentPlatform.mapLatest {
               FilterState(
                   parentPlatform = it,
                   platforms = it?.platforms
               )
           }
                .catch { cause ->

                }
                .collectLatest {
                    _filterState.value = it
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no problem with `parent` argument. I can pass it with no problem however the array type causing a crash with the following error:
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Arrays don't support default values.`

Comment: Did you read the [docs on passing custom types](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-kotlin-dsl#custom-types)? It even uses search filters as its example.

Comment: I did not see this. This solved my problem. Instead of just passing id and child platform ids as an argument I can pass the whole object as an argument now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When I see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-kotlin-dsl#custom-types), I look in the code of the `NavType.IntArrayType` to find out how it converts String (value from key-value query parameters of the screen route) to `IntArray`. There I found these two methods of parsing `String` into `IntArray`:

```
    public val IntArrayType: NavType<IntArray?> = object : NavType<IntArray?>(true) {
        //other methods skipped

        
        override fun parseValue(value: String): IntArray {
            return intArrayOf(IntType.parseValue(value))
        }

        override fun parseValue(value: String, previousValue: IntArray?): IntArray {
            return previousValue?.plus(parseValue(value)) ?: parseValue(value)
        }
    }
```

- `parseValue(value: String)`: converts single `String` value to a `IntArray` containing only one value.
- `parseValue(value: String, previousValue: IntArray?)`: add the new `value` to the `previousValue` array.

From this, I get to the conclusion that we can give an array as multiple key-value pair with the same key in query params then it will append all the value in a single array. Example :

`screen_name?platforms=1&platforms=2&platforms=3`

will result in `IntArray` containing [1,2,3] for key "platforms". For the first key (`platforms=1`), it will use `parseValue(value: String)` to convert that `Int` to `IntArray`. Thereafter, it will use `parseValue(value: String, previousValue: IntArray?)` to append further key values.

I have made an extension function for 'IntArray' and a generic extension function for any type of `Array` to convert them into nav args query parameters. You can use this in this way:

```
//function for only IntArray. You have to make function for each type 
//of array (LongArray, FloatArray etc)
fun IntArray.toNavArgs(key: String) : String = buildString {
    this@toNavArgs.forEachIndexed{ i, item ->
        if(i > 0) append("&")
        append("$key=$item")
    }
}

//generic function for any type of array
fun Array<*>.toNavArgs(key: String) : String = buildString {
    this@toNavArgs.forEachIndexed{ i, item ->
        if(i > 0) append("&")
        append("$key=$item")
    }
}
    //here is my filter bottom sheet
    bottomSheet(route = FILTER_ROUTE) {
        FilterDialog(viewModel = viewModel,
            navigateToPlatformScreen = { parentId: Int,platforms: Array<Int?> ->
                navController.navigate(
                    "${Screen.PlatformScreen.route}?" +
                            "parent=${parentId}" +
                            //add the platforms in the route if it is not empty
                            if(platforms.isNotEmpty()) 
                                "&${platforms.toNavArgs("platforms")}" 
                            else ""
                )
            })
    }

    //platforms screen
    bottomSheet(route = Screen.PlatformScreen.route+"?parent={parent}&platforms={platforms}",arguments = Screen.PlatformScreen.arguments) { backstackEntry ->
        val parent = backstackEntry.arguments?.getInt("parent")
        
        //get the IntArray from the arguments
        val platforms = backstackEntry.arguments?.getIntArray("platforms")
        
        PlatformScreen(parent = parent,platforms = platforms)
    }
```